# CronJob on EC2 not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have used these cronjobs on our previous LiquidWeb LAMP stack and it worked fine. Now on our new AWS setup, it won't work at all.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://website.com/reader.php
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://website.com/process/
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://website.com/subscription/instagramtag
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://website.com/subscription/twittertag
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://website.com/subscription/cron_follow
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://website.com/subscription/report/
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://www.website.com/subscription/twitter
```

I know these scripts work, there are no PHP errors, and obviously website.com is not the real address. Is it because we are on a micro-instance? Am I overloading the server?

Comment: Correction, the first script works fine.

Comment: what does the  system log say

Comment: is there any errors? check your mail.

Comment: why are you not calling the files via the command line `php file.php`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it was an issue w/ all of the SSL certs, these were run as https not http, I added in -k and they all worked.  Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Dagon, I am not using php file.php because this is a CodeIgniter site, and the script is called by the URL